# Insert a character as an item delimiter into string in R

Tags: r, regex

In R, I have a single string with multiple entries such as:

```
mydata <- c("(first data entry) (second data entry) (third data entry) ")
```

I want to insert the pipe symbol "|" between the entries as an item delimiter, ending up with the following list:

```
"(first data entry)|(second data entry)|(third data entry)"
```

Not all of the mydata rows are containing the same amount of entries. If mydata contains 0 or just 1 entry, then no "|" pipe symbol is required.

I've tried the following without success:

```
newdata <- paste(mydata, collapse = "|")
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `gsub(") (", ")|(", mydata, fixed=TRUE)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need a regex if you have consistent `)`+1 space+`(` pattern.

You can simply use

```r
gsub(") (", ")|(", mydata, fixed=TRUE)
```

If your strings contain variable amount of spaces, tabs, etc., you can use

```r
gsub("\\)\\s*\\(", ")|(", mydata)
gsub("\\)[[:space:]]*\\(", ")|(", mydata)
stringr::str_replace_all(mydata, "\\)\\s*\\(", ")|(")
```

Here, `\)\s*\(` pattern matches a `)` (escaped because `)` is a special regex metacharacter), then zero or more whitespaces, and then a `(`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TlHM7i/1).

If there is always one or more whitespaces between parentheses, use `\s+` instead of `\s*`.

Comment: All four solutions work as expected - [proof](https://tio.run/##K/r/P7cyJbEkUcFGVyFZQ0kjLbOouEQBLJKaV1JUqamgUZyanJ@XgipWkpFZhCqkpMmVXlyapKEElFXSAXJrQBTEcB2FtMyK1BTbkKBQV00uqLqYGM2YmGKtmBgM5ZoIFdHRVsUFicmpVrGx2FUWlxRl5qUXWVkBGfFFqQU5QMXxiTk5GjCbsdij@f8/AA).

Comment: I used look arounds here to great advantage :) Every day I followed your trail to have one regex exercise before I do my other assignments and hopefully in 50 years I will become as good as you. Thanks for inspiring :)

Answer (score 1):

This will replace the spaces with the "|" in your string. If you need more complex rules use regex with gsub.

```
gsub(") (",")|(", yourString)
```

Comment: `gsub(") (",")|(", yourString)` results in [*invalid regular expression ') (', reason 'Missing ')''*](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzK/tCi4pCgzL13BRlchWUNJIy2zqLhEISWxJFEhNa@kqFJTQaM4NTk/LwVVrCQjswhVSEmTK724NElDCSirpKOkWQMkFRDma/7/DwA)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the following solution too:

```
gsub("(?<=\\))\\s+(?=\\()", "|", mydata, perl = TRUE)

[1] "(first data entry)|(second data entry)|(third data entry) "
```

Comment: Yes, it will work. However, note that unanchored lookarounds prevent internal optimizations, each position will have to be checked. I'd rather use consuming counterpart in simple cases like this.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm sorry what are consuming counter parts? I'm still not quite familiar with these names.

Comment: I also first used `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` verbs for this, but it also leaves one `|` at the end.

Comment: `\)` is a consuming pattern. Regex puts the `)` into the match and advances the regex index to the position after `)`. `(?<=\))` is a non-consuming pattern. The engine checks if there is a `)` on the left, and returns true or false without updating the match text, nor advancing its index. It is best practice to stick to KISS principle. Keep it super simple.